# How can I get gnome-panel in ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: gnome-panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)
>   [How do I use the GNOME Panel in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39069/how-do-i-use-the-gnome-panel-in-unity)
>   [Is it possible to keep GNOME 2 in 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65069/is-it-possible-to-keep-gnome-2-in-11-10)

I want Gnome-panel in my ubuntu 11.10 to put netspeed applet in that panel.

Comment: The old Gnome Panel cannot be used in Gnome 3, which 11.10 uses.

Comment: A good answer can be found at [How to Revert to Gnome-Classic](http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)