# Install Gnome 2.32 in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to keep GNOME 2 in 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65069/is-it-possible-to-keep-gnome-2-in-11-10)

Is it possible to install Gnome 2.3x in Ubuntu 11.10?
If yes how?

Fallback mode wont do. It has to be Gnome 2.3x

Gnome Classic nor Xubuntu are options beacause neither of them support 3 or more monitors

Comment: ... simple answer - you can't install gnome 2 on 11.10.

Comment: So the only way is to downgrade to 11.04?

Comment: yes until 12months time when support has finished.  Alternatively choose something excellent like xubuntu.  If you havent already seen this question - give gnome-classic another try. http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.
However, fallback mode can be quite nice once you configure it right.
`sudo apt-get update gnome-session-fallback`
You need to alt+rightclick on the panels to configure them, then make it use Compiz instead of Metacity as window manager.

If you have a problem with Alt+rightclick not working, it is because Alt+mouseclicks are used to move/resize the window.
So make it use WinKey instead of Alt.
`gconftool-2 --set --type string /apps/metacity/general/mouse_button_modifier '<Super>'`